# adobe flash builder 4.6 keeps showing "not responding" previously did not happen. why is that the case?

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder4.5

I have several Adobe Flash Builder projects for 4.6.

in the main template mxml, i have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:dragdrop="org.robotlegs.demos.draganddrop.*"
                       xmlns:view="org.robotlegs.demos.draganddrop.view.*"
                       xmlns:buttons="org.robotlegs.demos.draganddrop.view.controls.buttons.*"
                       creationComplete="this.maximize()"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       maxWidth="1601"
                       maxHeight="1611">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        s|Application {
            background-alpha:"0.7"; 
            padding: 0px;

        }
    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <dragdrop:DragAndDropContext contextView="{this}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Image id="background" width="100%" height="100%" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
             scaleMode="zoom" source="@Embed('theme/assets/MaxBackground.png')"/>

    <s:BorderContainer id="layoutCanvas" width="100%" height="100%" visible="true" backgroundImage="background">

        <buttons:ApplicationClose right="5" top="2" id="applicationClose" />
        <buttons:ApplicationMaximize right="25" top="2" id="applicationMaximize" />
        <buttons:ApplicationMinimize right="45" top="2" id="applicationMinimize" />
        <buttons:Save left="25" top="2" id="saveThisStory" />
        <buttons:SaveAs left="55" top="2" id="saveThisStoryAs" />
        <buttons:AddPage left="85" top="2" id="addPageToStory" />

    </s:BorderContainer>


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Previously I can open this without any problems. Now the adobe flash builder just freezes up and shows a not responding in my task manager or activity monitor if you are using mac os x.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is uninstall the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

The reason is because you have this tab opened and everytime you attempt to open the FlashBuilder 4.6, it will attempt to open this file for editing, thus causing the non-response to happen again.

Second step is re-install the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

The reason is because of step1, so you need to reinstall.

Third step is attempt to open the same project again. Now that you have reinstall, the offending project is no longer in your explorer window.

**Should this resolve the issue, you can stop here. If it does not, proceed to next step.**

Fourth step is open the mxml with another editor say, TextEdit or Notepad.

Look for this offending line

```
<s:Image id="background" width="100%" height="100%" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
         scaleMode="zoom" source="@Embed('theme/assets/MaxBackground.png')"/>
```

Remove the smoothingQuality and smooth attributes

```
<s:Image id="background" width="100%" height="100%" 
         scaleMode="zoom" source="@Embed('theme/assets/MaxBackground.png')"/>
```

Save the file

Fifth step, now attempt to open the project using Flash Builder 4.6

Reason for the smoothingQuality and smooth affecting the non response is not known.

Comment: **"Second step is re-install the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6. The reason is because of step1, so you need to reinstall."**...You don't say!!! (I wish Stackoverflow would allow posting of memes) :P

Comment: and secondly, I don't believe the `smooth` and `smoothQuality` cause a problem because I use it regularly and I haven't noticed any problem.

Comment: I have repeatedly uninstall and reinstall on mac os x to no avail. I also tried to install on windows prompting the same issue. The situation was resolved only after removing the two attributes.

Also previously when the attributes were there, my flash builder 4.6 did not crash. Only recently.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Kimsia's answer and it worked out!!!

It's kind of funny, but that's the reason. I deactivated those same two offending attributes: 
`smooth="true"` and `smoothingQuality="high"` and FB is lightning fast now.

Hope it helps

Comment: your answer is not really an answer but more of a comment to my answer. you should write this as a comment in my answer. and if my answer helps, you can upvote it. this should help http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757